# g++ undefined reference to constructor , really simple code

Tags: c++

I made a program to test my knowledge on class but I had some troubles.

foo.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
private:
        int a;
public:
        foo();

};
```

foo.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"
using namespace std;



foo::foo()
{

a = 0;

}
```

And main.cc:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{

foo a;

return 0;


}
```

I compiled this with g++ main.cc -o main. Then I got

```
-bash-4.1$ g++ main.cc -o main
/tmp/cc5Hnes8.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `foo::foo()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think there should be a really stupid mistake here but I really cannot find it. I've been struggling on this whole night...

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `g++ -o main main.cc foo.cc`

Comment: Since you never mentioned `foo.cc` to the compiler, how do you expect the compiler to know anything about `foo.cc` and anything defined inside `foo.cc`?

Answer (score 3):

You are asking the compiler to not only translate `main.cc` but also perform the final link to produce the executable `main`. This second step cannot be done because `main.cc` references the function `foo::foo` whose definition is in `foo.cc` and therefore not available to the compiler. You can do this:

```
g++ main.cc -c -o main.o
g++ foo.cc -c -o foo.o
g++ main.o foo.o -o main
```

The `-c` flag makes the compiler perform translation only, so this separately compiles `main.cc` and `foo.cc` and then links the objects together to obtain the executable. In this way, the definition of `foo::foo` will end up inside `foo.o` and will be available at link time.

Or, you can just provide both `.cc` files. This basically does the same thing as the three commands above:

```
g++ main.cc foo.cc -o main
```

Answer (score 1):

You should compile all source (`.cc` in your case) files:

```
g++ main.cc foo.cc -o main
```

Answer (score -1):

When you realize the constructor of `foo` in `foo.cc`， you should compile it.

use `g++ main.cc foo.cc -o main`.